# How to add BottomTabNavigator inside the StackNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

this is function for tabNavigation

```
function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}/>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ScanQR"
        component={CameraScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={UpdateAccount}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

i have 3 stack which is for register, login to home, and home to other functionality

this is stack to home

```
function StackNavigatorHome() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="TabNavigator"
        component={TabNavigator}/>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Select Location"
        component={SelectLocation} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}/>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeToCheckOut"
        component={HomeToCheckOut}/>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Other Location"
          component={Others1}
        />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

this is stack for register

```
function StackNavigatorRegister() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={Login}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="CreateNewSecurity"
          component={CreateNewSecurity} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Personal New Security"
          component={PersonalNewSecurity}/>
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

this is login to home

```
function StackNavigatorLogin() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={Login}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="StackNavigatorHome"
          component={StackNavigatorHome}/>
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

this is my main function of app

```
export default function RootStack() {
  let auth = useAppSelector(state => state.auth);
  console.log(auth);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {auth.isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <StackNavigatorLogin />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <StackNavigatorRegister />
        </>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Right now, i'm having trouble to deal with stack. For early stack, it show the bottomTabNavigation at Home, ScanQR, SettingProfile. Once i click another page which is HomeToCheckOut then, it not show the bottomTabNavigation.

Im expecting that, how to properly manage stack and for other page also can be see the BottomTabNavigation. I tried many codes already, but it doesnt not helping me. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BottomTabNavigator` must be the top-level navigator for otherwise the bottom tabs will disappear if you navigate to another screen which is not a screen defined in the `BottomTabNavigator`. In your current code, the top-level navigator is `StackNavigatorLogin` (or `StackNavigatorRegister`, depending on the authentication state). The `StackNavigatorLogin` stack contains `StackNavigatorHome` which contains `TabNavigator`. However, the `HomeToCheckOut` screen is not defined as a screen inside `TabNavigator` (or any nested navigator defined in `TabNavigator`).

I would suggest the following solution for your current setup:

- Replace `StackNavigatorHome` with `TabNavigator` in `StackNavigatorLogin`
- Add `StackNavigatorHome` as the first screen in `TabNavigator`
- Add `Home` as the first screen in `StackNavigatorHome`

The above suggestions yield the following code:

```js
function StackNavigatorLogin() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LogIn"
          component={Login}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="TabNavigator"
          component={TabNavigator}/>
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="StackNavigatorHome"
        component={StackNavigatorHome}/>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ScanQR"
        component={CameraScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={UpdateAccount}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function StackNavigatorHome() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}/>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Select Location"
        component={SelectLocation} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeToCheckOut"
        component={HomeToCheckOut}/>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Other Location"
          component={Others1}
        />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried to follow your suggestion, however each of button show the errors when i clicked on them. The errors occurs "Do you have a screen named 'StackNavigatorHome'?" and "Do you have a screen named 'CreateNewSecurity'?". Based what you said which is "However, the HomeToCheckOut screen is not defined as a screen inside TabNavigator (or any nested navigator defined in TabNavigator", may i know why it does not have any nested navigator?

Comment: It depends where and how you try to use the navigation object. The error message suggests that you navigate to a screen with a navigation object that is passed by  a navigator that does not define that screen. For `StackNavigatorHome`, the tab navigation button should work since the navigator contains that stack. The CreateNewSecurity screen is not defined as a tab. I don‘t understand your second question, I‘m afraid.